# Colorize or mark the differences of GoogleTest ASSERT_STREQ

Tags: c++, unit-testing, windows-7, googletest

If you want to compare C strings with Google Test you will use `ASSERT_STREQ(expected, actual)` for easier handling: is there a possibility to colorize or mark the differences? (like in file compare tools)

Comment: As ever with formatted output, you're going to have to be more specific about your platform and desired output mechanism. Assuming text to ANSI-compatible terminal, you could hack Google Test to inject ANSI control characters to create red and green....

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Sorry. Windows 7 terminal